# Client Socket in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, server, tcp, client

I'm having trouble getting data from a socket. This is the client (below) where "_sender" is the socket. What I want is to have a buffer of the same size as the bytes received from the server (which I don't know a priori). So what I do is check how many bytes the socket ("_sender") is ready to receive from the server by means of the "Available" statement.
Do you think this reasoning is correct?

```
byte[] bufferRec = new byte[0]; 
        int bytesAvailable = 0;
        int offset = 0;

        System.Console.WriteLine(_sender.Available);
        
        while (_sender.Available != 0)
        {
            bytesAvailable = _sender.Available; 
            Array.Resize(ref bufferRec, bufferRec.Length + bytesAvailable); 
            int read = _sender.Receive(bufferRec, offset, bytesAvailable, SocketFlags.None); 
            offset += read;
        }
```

Comment: What is actually the problem that you have?

Comment: If this is a TCP socket then you need  to use some protocol over it, and as such you must know beforehand how many bytes you need to read, then read until you read that many. For example you can prefix the "message" with its length in bytes, and send that length using first 2 or 4 bytes. Then receiver first reads exactly 2(4) bytes, now it knows length of the message and it reads exactly that much.

Answer (score 1):

A socket is a continuous stream of bytes.  The stream only stops when the other end stops sending.

Think of the stream just like a binary file on the disk, you need to understand how that binary file is "framed" you need to know where the bits and the bytes start and stop.

eg,

```
Byte[0..3]             = MessageID
Byte[4..5]             = MessageSize in Bytes
Byte[6..6+MessageSize] = Payload
```

Now you'd read bytes 0-5, then extract the payload, get the Message size and read the payload from the stream.  Then you'd repeat that.

Of course you also need error handling, what happens if the stream ends before the payload is extracted, this could happen if the server goes off line.  This is a akin to a file on the disk being damaged and curt short.